# Validate hidden upload field angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation, typescript, file-upload

I need to validate a hidden input file field with Angularjs, Ngdirty or other expression does not work with hidden element.

```
<form name="myForm">
<label for="selectFileForImport"  class="form-control boldFormInputText" ng-class="{ 'has-error':!ctrl.isValidFile()&&myForm.myFile.$dirty,'valid-file':ctrl.isValidFile()}"></label>
<input type="file" accept=".csv" name="myFile" id="selectFileForImport" file="ctrl.file" ng-hide="true" required>
</form>
```

Controller :

```
isValidFile(): boolean {
        return (this.file != null  && this.getFileExtension(this.file.name.toLowerCase()) == 'csv');
    }
```

CSS :

```
 .has-error{
    border-color: red;
}

    .valid-file{
        border-color: green;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? And please provide some more code for context.

Comment: When removing ng-hide the validation work fine and the class is applied, with ng-hide, visibility : hidden or display : none , the ngdirty does not work